# My button works only after the page is refreshed

Tags: javascript, button

So I spent some time trying to figure this issue myself before coming here as a last resort. I could always see my dice roll number in the console but it wouldn't show in the DOM.It was being shown as undefined. I had to go back in fix my code, creating global variables for finding my random number and then using them inside my functions. I also figured out having console.log in my functions were returning my functions as undefined, so I removed them as well. So at this point I can run the functions and now see both the dice number show in the DOM, and if I run a console.log() outside the function, I can see the dice number in the console as well, great, success. So now here's comes the issue of the button. I can get the dice to roll when I click the button and that's great, but it won't roll again when it's clicked. The only way it will roll again is when I refresh the page. I don't know what to do at this point, I've tried a few different things, my functions are working for my dice roll, those are tested, and my button is working, it's just not rolling again when clicked. Any idea on why this is happening? I would appreciate anyone's time in helping me with this and letting know where I'm going wrong. I'm new to programming so I'm still making mistakes as I go along. Thank you for your time.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags-->
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta
      name="viewport"
      content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no"
    />

    <meta name="description" content="Kenzie" />
    <meta name="author" content="Kenzie" />
    <meta name="keywords" content="Kenzie" />

    <!-- Title Page-->
    <title>Kenzie JS and the DOM Assessment</title>

    <!-- CSS-->
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" media="all" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <!-- Your HTML Here! -->
    <button id="roll">Roll a Pair of Dice</button>
    <div id="result"></div>
    <div id="graph"></div>
    <script src="code.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>


let results = [null, null, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0];

// Your Code Here!

let x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1
let y = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1

function rollDie(){
   return x
}

function rollDice(){
  return x + y
  }


let roll = document.getElementById("roll")
let throwDice = roll.addEventListener('click',() => {
let k=  rollDice();
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML= `You rolled a ${k}!`

})


console.log(rollDice());
```

Comment: Why is your javascript on top on your <!DOCTYPE> and not in a different file ? I guess if your JS code is on top of your HTML, it will not have loaded the <div> element when you are trying to add the listener to it

Comment: Move the `let x`/`let y` into the `rollDice` function. As-is, you are initializing those variables once and reusing those results in each click event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you press your button the function `rollDice()` will be executed. The problem is it keeps displaying the same number. Thats because you`re not actually 'rolling' the Dice.
Try this

```
function rollDice(){
    x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1
    y = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1
    return x + y
}
```